# Set wp-content folder to Dropbox folder

Tags: wp-config, configuration, xampp

Ideally I would like to do this with both my PC and Mac OSX boxes, but for now I would be thrilled with just the Mac OSX.

I am trying to keep my WP Themes & Plugin Local Development synced using Dropbox. I am using XAMPP for both Windows and Mac as my LAMP Stack and am wondering what I have to set in order to get the Mac. Based off the Codex I can do this via setting these two items:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/somedir');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/somedir');
```

I am successful in changing `WP_CONTENT_DIR` to */Users/seth/Dropbox/Xammp-Content/wordpress/wp-content/*, which allows me to see my available themes and activate them, however any of the resources (styles.css, images, etc.) doesn't resolve and thus I have a bunch of failed GETs on the resources and the theme is unstyled.

Upon further inspection this is the URL resolved for styles.css

> *http://localhost:8080/wp-content/themes/[theme-name]/styles.css*

Which again is a failed resource to load.

I have no idea what to set `WP_CONTENT_URL` to...

Any help? Appreciate it.

Comment: So what is your local domain? And what port are you using? Without such info it's really hard to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an alias to your Dropbox folder so those files can be accessed on your server. This can be done in `httpd.conf`:

```
Alias /dropbox /Users/seth/Dropbox
```

Or you could make a direct alias to the real `wp-content` folder:

```
Alias /wp-content /Users/seth/Dropbox/Xammp-Content/wordpress/wp-content/
```

Then set `WP_CONTENT_URL` in `wp-config.php` appropriately:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://localhost/dropbox/Xammp-content/wordpress/wp-content' );
```

Answer (score 4):

I use Dropbox as well, but not directly linked as the Dropbox folder path could differ from install to install. My Dropbox just is the root of my bare git repository.

#### Simplified...

When I start coding, I just add a new folder to my Dropbox and `--bare init` it.

```
// Inside your Dropbox/webdev/themes folder for e.g.
git --bare init
```

Then inside your new Theme folder you simply init a default repo.

```
git init
```

Finally just work, `git push dropbox master` and `git clone etc.` when you're doing a new setup on another machine or use `git pull etc.` when you're switching machines.

Comment: I went with this technique although it was outside my desired path of the question.